# Expired "authentication token" for user with deleted password

Tags: cron, password, pam

**The Setup:**

1) The user's password was deleted with "passwd -d " command

2) The user has cron jobs running

**The Problem:**
Once every 30 days (default password expiration policy) the cron fails with an error

```
Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
ERROR: failed to open PAM security session: Success
ERROR: cannot set security context
```

**My Questions:**
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
Why is the authentication token expired for a user with deleted password?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on a Debian 8 DigitalOcean droplet created using the 'user data' (web-form-posted setup script (bash or cloud-init)) option.

*check systemd journal for relevant error messages:*

> journalctl | grep -B 1 -i "cron.*authentication token" | tail -n 3

```
May 19 13:17:01 debian-512mb-fra1-01 CRON[16714]: pam_unix(cron:account): expired password for user root (root enforced)
May 19 13:17:01 debian-512mb-fra1-01 CRON[16714]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 19 13:17:01 debian-512mb-fra1-01 cron[470]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
```

*see which account(s) have expired status*

> cut -d: -f 1 /etc/passwd | while read U ; do chage -l $U | sed
>   "s|^|$U:|"; done | grep "must be"

```
root:Last password change                   : password must be changed
root:Password expires                   : password must be changed
root:Password inactive                  : password must be changed
```

*use 'chage' tool to update expiry fields, first attempt*

> chage -I -1 -m 0 -M 999999 -W 31 root

*Note: didn't have the desired effect until I also added the 'last-changed' option (-d)*

*use 'chage' tool to update expiry fields, second attempt*

> chage -d `date "+%F"` -E 2999-01-01 -I -1 -m 0 -M 999999 -W 31
>   root

*check the field expiry*

> chage -l root

```
Last password change                    : May 19, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : Jan 01, 2999
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 999999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 31
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your system removed the password but did not clear the password expiration requirements.

If this is the case you can clear these manually using `vipw` -- The affected field will either be in the `passwd` file or the `shadow` file depending on your OS (See `man 5 passwd` and `man 5 shadow` for details on the file formats so you know which field(s) you need to clear)

Comment: If you update your question to include a specific OS tag and leave a comment here and I'll come back and update this answer with specifics for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu my **/etc/shadow** file was missing *(though there was an /etc/shadow-)* so all I did was run...

```
sudo pwconv
```

...And it fixed this issue for me by recreating the /etc/shadow file.

*(Though I can not yet confirm this is a long term fix, it may last until the password change/expire time or until some other factor happens) --- someone back me up or correct me*